# Jenkins pipeline script to trigger other pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a parent pipeline job with stages that call trigger other jobs, which are also pipeline jobs.

Can I achieve this?

Here is a skeleton of what I want:
Parent job's script:

```groovy
pipeline {
  parallel{
    stage("A") {
         build 'name of job 1 which is a pipeline job again and has a parallel block with stages in it'
    }
    stage("B") {
         build 'name of job 2 which is a pipeline job again and has a parallel block with stages in it'
   }
    stage("C") {
         build 'name of job 3 which is a pipeline job again and has a parallel block with stages in it'
   }
 }
}
```

Does it work this way? Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: did you try it out?

Comment: not really, you can create test jobs and do this in less than 5 mins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure does,
This is what we are using, we promote between environments by kicking off the same job from the current execution and don't wait for the result.

```
    build(job: "org/${jobName}/${BRANCH_NAME}", 
    parameters: [
        new StringParameterValue('ENV', env),
        new StringParameterValue('ENV_NO', env_no),
        new StringParameterValue('ARTIFACT_NAME', params.ARTIFACT_NAME)
    ],
    propagate: false, 
    wait: false,
)
```

Refer to the reference for all options
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/